# How do I declare IEGetProtectedModeCookie in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

```
<DllImport("ieframe.dll", EntryPoint:="IEGetProtectedModeCookie")> _
Public Function IEGetProtectedModeCookie( _
    <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lpszURL As String, _
    <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lpszCookieName As String, _
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszCookieData As StringBuilder, _
    ByRef pcchCookieData As UInteger, _
    ByVal dwFlags As UInteger) As Integer
End Function
```

First of all this seems to be very different than my regular API declaration

```
Declare Function InternetGetCookieEx Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetGetCookieExA" (ByVal pchURL As String, ByVal pchCookieName As String, ByVal pchCookieData As String, ByRef pcchCookieData As System.UInt32, ByVal dwFlags As System.UInt32, ByVal lpReserved As Integer) As Boolean
```

Moreoever it simply doesn't compile. StringBuilder is not defined. MarshalAs is not defined. In is not define. I wonder what I should include or import to make them work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the .Net way of declaring API functions.
(`Declare Function` was inherited from VB6)

You need to import `System.Text` and `System.Runtime.InteropServices`

Comment: those marshalas(unmanagedtype) looks ugly. Why the vb6 version doesn't contain that? Can I just use the vb6 version?

Comment: @JimThio: Sometimes.  `MarshalAs` is more powerful than the VB6 syntax and is sometimes necessary for unusual API methods.